# render dynamic HTML with wicked pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wicked-pdf

I have a DSL that renders HTML.  If I manually generate HTML in the console, and save it as a view (as an experiment, there's no reason to do this), so that it lives in app/views/manifests as show.pdf.erb, and then I simply render the PDF using Wicked's/Rails built in rendering, everything works great and looks great.  Now, because this is dynamic HTML, meaning it can change based on the data, what I have to do is generate the HTML as a string, and then use Wicked's pdf_from_string:

```
html = HtmlGenerator.parse_node node, "root", @manifest
pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html) # note, this is the same HTML that looks great as a view
```

and then send it to the browser

```
send_data(pdf, 
:filename => "my_pdf_name.pdf", 
:disposition => 'inline')
```

Now, everything is screwed up. It appears like the fonts are 15% bigger, all of my rows are screwed up.  Does the rendering routine in WickedPDF use a different formatting that pdf_from_string?

Thanks for any help,
Kevin

Comment: Dont these pdd generatora use your print css? Might explain the issues.

Comment: Is it related to table structure?Can you explain more about this issue?